# xpi can not install?

Tags: ant, firefox-addon, installation, xpi

i create an empty firefox extension  project through eclpse+spket and then edit install.rdf
like this

```
 <em:minVersion>1.5</em:minVersion>
 <em:maxVersion>33.0.0.*</em:maxVersion>
```

I run ant  build.xml and create *.xpi  successful,but when i try install it in firefox,it cant not be installed,just shown "the extension can not be installed,it might has broken".
My firefox's version is 32.0,the newest version and i have checked the structure of xpi package,which accord with the right standard of mozilla request.
what's the problem?
tks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this shouldn't be causing xpi to not install, but for sure AMO (addons.mozilla.org) won't accept this as max version is unacceptable. See [AMO :: Application Versions](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/pages/appversions/) for valid strings you can put in min and max version.

After fixing that then try installing xpi, if it works, real cool!

After reading the link i posted above, your max version should be `33.*`